# Google showing confusing consent screen

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm authorizing for Google Calendar usage from a .NET web application.
Here's the url I made: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar&redirect_uri=my_redirect_url&response_type=code&client_id=my_client_id&access_type=offline.

 What I expected is the consent screen would say something like 'This application would like to access to your calendar', but it just says 'Have offline access'. Isn't that confusing? Did I miss something?

Comment: You request url is correct, and it should work, so it also confuses me. What happens if you request without access_type?

Comment: the same thing. I suspect this behaviour may be because I granted access to Calendar before.

Comment: would you mind posting picture of the consent screen its giving you?

Comment: actually, I solved this - I found out that Dane was right. I revoked the access to the calendar, then the consent screen was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will say "Have offline access" when you have previously granted calendar access but did not de-authorize the app before being prompted again.